# Smart pointer analog of `std::shared_ptr` with API to bind callbacks to refcount-modifying events e.g. release/retain … is this a thing?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am in need of a smart-pointer structure – analogous to `std::shared_ptr` – that offers me some kind of API with exposed hooks, to which callbacks to refcount-modifying events (like e.g. release/retain, aka refcout increment/decrement) can be bound.

I either want to implement this myself, or use something off-the-shelf, should it exist.

Like, I would like to optimally be able to say “Invoke this callable whenever you increment the refcount [but that one when decremementing]” while defining this putative `shared_ptr`-ish smart pointer (much as delete-expressions and deleter functors are used, respectively, in `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` definitions).

---

EDIT (from my comment below) – Here’s why I want this: I currently have an Image class template that, at its heart, has a std::shared_ptr holding a (potentially large) contiguous heap-allocated memory block. Image has inner classes implementing hyperslab iterators (exposing e.g. color planes, CBIR hash data, &c) that use std::weak_ptr to refer back to the memory block of the owning Image instance. I want to extend Image for specific refcounted runtimes – for example the Python c-api – and tying into the existing std::shared_ptr refcounter apparatus is preferable to keeping two disparate systems in sync.

Comment: How about http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html ?

Comment: @ForEveR I don’t quite think so – `boost::intrusive_ptr` seems to have started out as a sort of Australopithecine version of `std::smart_ptr` that has evolved along separate lines and now offers a smaller memory footprint and a user-implemented “control block”; AFAIA it is not really about hooking retain/release type events with callables. I really, really don’t know though. Can you or another expert weigh in?

Comment: Do you want to define the callables per process, per thread, per type, or per instance?

Comment: This might guide: http://www.boost.org/community/counted_body.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck either per-type with a functor struct (á la `std::unique_ptr`) or, alternatively, per-instance with a callable on construction. I prefer the former (and as long as I am making stuff up I’d also like a pony) as it makes the practical use of the smart pointer `typedef`/`using`-friendly

Comment: EDIT: reworded some of the question language, based on feedback on meta.stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give a constructive or even useful answer without knowing *why* you need to do it. Remember that your callbacks are generally critical sections, so you're limited in what you can do in them, and you'd be horribly breaking the performance of your shared pointer by holding such critical sections. The pointer itself is usually only using atomic operations.

Comment: Sure, I’d be happy to explain: I currently have an `Image` class template that, at its heart, has a `std::shared_ptr` holding a (potentially large) contiguous heap-allocated memory block. `Image` has inner classes implementing hyperslab iterators (exposing e.g. color planes, CBIR hash data, &c) that use `std::weak_ptr` to refer back to the memory block of the owning `Image` instance. I want to extend `Image` for specific refcounted runtimes – for example the Python c-api – and tying into the existing `std::shared_ptr` refcounter apparatus is preferable to keeping two disparate systems in sync.

Comment: @KubaOber Does that make sense?

Comment: Is your `Image` class an implicitly or explicitly shared value class, then? If so, just hold its copy from the shim class exposed to python and you're set. If it's not a shared value class, then it shouldn't be using `std::shared_ptr` to hold image data of course. It's perfectly fine not to deal with the internal implementation detail of your `Image` class: since that's what the internal `shared_ptr` is! No users of that class should be aware of that. The python shim is just such a user, it should approach the class as any other user would: by holding it by value or by a separate `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @KubaOber Indeed `Image` is shared-value by design (it interoperates with the Halide imaging runtime in this way). As per your advice – my idea was to actually double down on not dealing with implementation details, so to speak; of all the reference-counting schemes I have had to deal with I like `shared_ptr` the most, because you never have to deal with the actual refcounting as it is handled so neatly by RAII; my thought was that I could leverage that – either internally or on the shim as you suggest – to avoid doing e.g. `Py_INCREF()` and friends ad nauseum (which I am historically bad at).

Comment: The Pythonic reference counting on the shim has to be done anyway, and must be separate from any other reference counting - so it'd be bad design to roll that into the `Image` class itself. These concerns are separate at a fundamental level. I really don't see a problem or need for any special solution here at all. Have the `Py_Image` hold an `Image` value and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `shared_ptr` has `shared_ptr`'s that are sharing an object all pointing to a so-called control block. It is this control block that holds the reference counters and is thus the object that more naturally can react to reference count changes.

But if you really want to do it via a smart pointer the following might work:

```
using std::shared_ptr;

template<class T> class sharedX_ptr;

// the type of function to call when a refcount change happens
template<class T>
void inc_callback(const sharedX_ptr<T>& p)
{
  std::cout << "Increasing refcount via " << &p
            << ", for object: " << p.get() << ", use_count: " << p.use_count()
            << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void dec_callback(const sharedX_ptr<T>& p)
{
  std::cout << "About to decrease refcount via " << &p
            << ", for object: " << p.get() << ", use_count: " << p.use_count()
            << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
class sharedX_ptr : public shared_ptr<T>
{
  typedef void (*callback)(const sharedX_ptr<T>&);
  callback inc, dec;
public:
  typedef shared_ptr<T> base;

  sharedX_ptr(const sharedX_ptr& p) : base(p), inc(p.inc), dec(p.dec)
  { if (this->get()) inc(*this); }

  template<class U>
  sharedX_ptr(sharedX_ptr<U>&& p) : base(std::move(p)), inc(p.inc), dec(p.dec)
  { /*if (this->get()) inc(*this);*/ }

  template<class U>
  sharedX_ptr(shared_ptr<U> p, callback i = inc_callback<T>, callback d = dec_callback<T>)
    : shared_ptr<T>(std::move(p)), inc(i), dec(d)
    { if (this->get()) inc(*this); }

  sharedX_ptr& operator=(sharedX_ptr&& p) {
    if (this != &p) {
      if (this->get()) dec(*this);
      base::operator=(std::move(p)); inc = p.inc; dec = p.dec;
      /* if (this->get()) inc(*this); */
    }
    return *this;
  }

  template<class U>
  sharedX_ptr& operator=(const sharedX_ptr& p) {
    if (this != &p) {
      if (this->get()) dec(*this);
      base::operator=(p); inc = p.inc; dec = p.dec;
      if (this->get()) inc(*this);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  void reset() { if (this->get()) dec(*this); shared_ptr<T>::reset();}

  ~sharedX_ptr() { if (this->get()) dec(*this); }
};
```

Comment: Wow, does this actually work? Can you post a link on e.g. ideone if it does?? That’d be awesome. Personally I am always leery of using inheritance to extend a crazy-complex `std`-namespace type like `std::shared_ptr` so I am always interested in cases where in fact inheritance is a viable route.

Comment: @fish2000 Thisyhooks into the operations that can change the ref-count, and piggybacks your callbacks on them. It "works", but don't try to use these pointers in more than one thread (I don't mean *at once*, I mean *ever*). An implementation that would be safe to use on multiple threads needs a completely different approach, and there's no way to sensibly reuse a `std::shared_ptr` to implement that since you have to replace almost all of it - it's less work to start from scratch.

Comment: @KubaOber thanks, yeah, that is exactly what I was afraid of (particularly the “I mean ever” part)

Comment: Note that there are missing `std::move` in your methods using r-value reference. And as resource is moved, calling the callback might be omitted (depend of requirement...).

Comment: @KubaOber, I'm sure you are correct, but perhaps you could go into a little more detail about which problems you get using this in combination with multiple threads.

Comment: @fish2000, have a look at http://ideone.com/N1C3jN. It is an adaptation of some code demonstrating the use of shared_ptr's from one of those C++ reference sites.

Comment: When either callback is executed, you can only know that one or more instances of the object exist. I don't know how could that be considered helpful. You cannot, for example, use the callbacks for any sort of reasoning about whether a particular number of objects exist.